# responsive background image with css

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

This is such a strange issue - I'm trying to add in a responsive background image to a really simple site, and I can see that image flicker on the screen while the page loads, however when the page load is complete the image disappears and I'm left with a white background.

Here's the css:

```
body {
  background: url('#') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Here's the [site](http://www.lesliebruce.com/).

Comment: link is not working can you please add screen shot

Answer (score 0):

This is something that your theme is doing, using `Javascript`. If you look in [here](http://www.lesliebruce.com/wp-content/themes/lobo/js/main.js), you will see the line

```
`$("#main-wrapper").animate({ opacity: 1 }, 750);`
```

This is run when the page initialises, and causes the opacity of the`main-wrapper` element to animate it's opacity, causing the fade you are seeing.

Your options are:

- Change your theme to a different one, or
- Create a [child theme](https://managewp.com/how-to-create-a-child-theme) and then edit the main.js file to remove the offending line. This has the advantage that you can keep all the theme, and your change will be protected from theme updates.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that all your elements have an opaque background-color. The image is there, it is just covered up by everything else. Remove the backgrounds from all the child elements, or use a rgba color.

Answer (score -1):

the problem is your every `<div>` has background and you are applying background image on body, Applying any thing on `body` will not help you as i see you buy this theme from someone you need to ask them how to add background on this site.

Answer (score -2):

Try bootstrap. You can add a background image to a container

```
<div class="container background">
</div>
```

your css

```
.background {
     ................

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. This is a Wordpress site, where should I put the `<div class="container background">`? In the header.php file?

Comment: simply you can add bootstrap plugin to the site & You can edit the header php file